# Why does my preloader not disappear once the website is loaded?

Tags: html, css, preloader

I have been watching multiple videos on how to implement preloaders and tried to follow them but never end up with a preloader that disappears once the website is loaded.

This is one of the methods that I've tried:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#loading {
  background:#020d1d url('images/preloader.gif') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 10%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testing preloader</title>
</head> 

<body onload="myFunction()">
  
  <div id="loading"></div>

  <div class="randomImg">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/2000x2000" alt="RandomImage">
  </div>

  <script>
    var preloader = document.getElementsById('loading');
    function myFunction() {
      preloader.style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Its just a typo error ```document.getElementById('#loading');``` correct it and it works just fine or as you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `getElementById` not `getElementsById` (no `s`)

Comment: I now know what people are referring to when saying that a simple letter can cause hours of frustration.

Comment: just pay attention to console messages, they are very helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you better look at function `MyFunction()`, you will see that u made mistake at line `var preloader = document.getElementsById('loading');`,  specifically on the part `getElementsById`, which you need to replace with `getElementById`.